# Copy a file with batch in a user selected directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i'm looking for a .bat file that, on opening, ask the user what folder he want to select, then, the batch copy a file (python script) in this folder and execute it

for now i use :

```
xcopy c:/pythonfiletocopy d:/destinationpath
```

but i dont find a way to make the user choose the destination folder

any idea ?

thank you

Comment: Choose, suggests you want the user input to be from a defined set of locations, can you please clarify the requirements; thank you.

Comment: sorry if it's not clear, i dont need a graphic interface, just a copy/past 
 - in the cmd window is fine - 
the user will launch the .bat. - 
the bat will ask what folder user want to treat 
- user copy past the adress of the folder
- then the bat do the copy action and launch the python script (this part is ok for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request user input using the `Set` command together with its `/P` option.

Here's an example which should accept typed or pasted input and should also accept drag and drop *for directories not containing spaces*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "_in=" & Set /P "_in=Please provide a directory for the file: "
If Defined _in If Exist "%_in%\" Echo XCopy "C:\pythonfiletocopy" "%_in%"
Pause
```

*I have added an `Echo` on line `3`, if you're happy with the output you can remove that.*

---

I know you said you didn't need one but you could `JScript` launch a GUI directory browser for input.

Here's an example which may do that:

```bat
0</* :
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('CScript //E:JScript //NoLogo "%~f0" 2^>Nul'
) Do Echo XCopy "C:\pythonfiletocopy" "%%A"
Pause
Exit /B */0;
var Folder=new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application').BrowseForFolder(0,'',1,'::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}');
try{new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(Folder.Self.Path)};catch(e){};close();
```

*I have added an `Echo` on line `4`, if you're happy with the output you can remove it and line `5`.*

Comment: perfect ! thank you
  - about user interface, i will consider it for the next one, i have a lot to learn befor :) thank you